# Should SO Careers be free to students?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I attended the Cambridge Stackoverflow Dev day. Joel said that Stackoverflow careers would be completely free for students.

However, upon inspection, I found that it states that students would only get one year of free filing. Shouldn't it be free as long as one is a student?

Comment: Is your name Van Wilder?

Answer (score 4):

It is free for one year as a student. That's because in order to take a full time job (the goal of most students, eventually, yes?) you have to finish school.

The free year is intended to overlap with part of your senior / final year as a student.

Comment: In my case, I started school after I got a full time job.  Do I really get a free ride on careers for the next 4-5 years?

Comment: no, because you can only tick the box once.

Comment: My plan has been foiled!

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I'm a freshman though, looking for internships. I could wait till my senior year (that's year 3 here) to tick that box.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it be free as long as one is a student?

No, you aren't looking for a job for the entire time.  In most parts of the world, students are full-time students and the expectation is that they'll focus primarily on schooling and not working.

On the other hand, I worked full-time throughout my education so I can see that for some minority it would have significant value.

Of course, if you think it's not fair I suppose you could request that they give you as much free time on the careers service as the rest of us working stiffs get... ;-D

Comment: it does have a drop down menu for internship

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I've revised my post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SO Careers should be free to all developers looking for jobs... why charge them? I am sure they can make a very nice profit charging Employers only.

Comment: One of the reasons to charge the employees is to eliminate all those people whoa aren't really looking for a new job, but simply keep their resume out on all the free jobsites just in case something better comes along.  It guarantees the employers a higher quality (or at least more motivated) potential employee, and keeps the number of stale, old, or unmanaged CVs out of the search.  Of course, it also increases SO's bottom line, and that can't be a bad thing... ;-D

Comment: Good point, however you could resolve the issue of "stale, old, or unmanaged CVs" by expiring them after 30 - 60 days... The point about increasing SO's bottom line is a valid point and I agree with you on that.